# Let's get critical: Nov 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Anime & Manga Stack Exchange](http://anime.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What do the black and red scenes mean?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5325/what-do-the-black-and-red-scenes-mean)

  **Net Score: 16** (Excellent: 17, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Why does connecting an automail hurt?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5404/why-connecting-an-automail-hurts)

  **Net Score: 11** (Excellent: 12, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How much time does the original Fullmetal Alchemist anime cover?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5471/how-much-time-does-the-original-fullmetal-alchemist-anime-cover)

  **Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 11, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [In episode 1 of Hyouka, what was the topic of the essay Houtarou has to rewrite?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5199/in-episode-1-of-hyouka-what-was-the-topic-of-the-essay-houtarou-has-to-rewrite)

  **Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What's the significance of the 'w' finger position in Elfen Lied?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5472/whats-the-significance-of-the-w-finger-position-in-elfen-lied)

  **Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Was Krillin based on the Turkish folk character Keloglan?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5294/was-krillin-based-on-the-turkish-folk-character-keloglan)

  **Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 13, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How much can something that is attached to a blood seal be damaged?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5463/how-much-can-something-that-is-attached-to-a-blood-seal-be-damaged)

  **Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5270/can-someone-tell-me-the-name-of-this-manga

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 11, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [Is Blue exorcist really based on a slush puppy?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5319/is-blue-exorcist-really-based-on-a-slush-puppy)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5254/who-is-this-anime-girl-character

  **Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 8)

---